# How to create a routing connection from client site to pc server?

Tags: c#, mysql-workbench

I am using Mifarecard reader to connect with the website. Mifarecard reader is connect with user laptop/desktop, due to it use USB connection only. Next, IPv6 localhost address is 192.168.71.155, due to the application is published at the server PC. When user access the link of http://192.168.71.155/Canteen%20UAT%20-%20MeiSynn/Order, two IPv6 address is get from Server PC and client PC, but there is no router/hub, they wouldn’t communicate. It’s causing the reader connect failed[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WBEtb.png). Any suggestion for solve this issue? 'm new beginner here...

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DateTime CurrentDate = DateTime.Now;
            DateTime sixhoursbefore = CurrentDate.AddHours(-5.50);
            Date.Text = sixhoursbefore.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
            //Dates.Text = sixhoursbefore.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");
            if (Session["Username"] == null)
            {
                Response.Redirect("Login.aspx?url=" + Server.UrlEncode(Request.Url.AbsoluteUri));
            }
            else if (Session["Username"] != null)
            {
                Master.GetLabel.Visible = true;
                Master.getLoginBtn.Visible = false;
                Master.GetLabel.Text = "Welcome " + Session["Username"];
                Master.getlogoutbtn.Visible = true;
                Master.getregbtn.Visible = false;
                MifareCard.Focus();
            }
            else if (Calc_results.Text == "")
            {
                Calc_results.Focus();
            }
            else
            {
                Button10.Focus();
            }

            //Get IPv6 of PC Server, due to this code published at there
            IPHostEntry host;
            string ipAdd = "?";
            host = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName());

            foreach (IPAddress ip in host.AddressList)
            {
                if (ip.AddressFamily.ToString() == "InterNetwork")
                {
                    ipAdd = ip.ToString();
                }
            }
            ErrorMsg0.Text = ipAdd;

            // USB Mifarecard Reader Connection
            icdev = Reader.hc_init(100,9600);
            
            if(icdev.ToInt32() <= 0)
            {
                Label11.Text = "Reader connect failed " + icdev.ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                Label11.Text = "Reader connected";
            }                
        }
```

Comment: What is it you are actually trying to do? Let the server access the card reader? Also, the addresses posted are IPv4 addresses, not IPv6.

Comment: Sorry.... is IPv4. I was published my application at server, then user can access the website.   Izit possible let the server access the card reader (when user access the website)?

Comment: A server cannot access arbitrary USB devices of the clients. You need either a standardized protocol, like for webcameras, or some plugin or custom software.

Comment: Thanks Jonash. Finally, I'm understand. Any recommend the plugin or custom software?